# List of Date + Hours between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

This gives me MM/DD/YYYY:

```
SELECT TRUNC (to_date('01/02/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') - ROWNUM + 1) dt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ( TO_DATE('01/02/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') - to_date('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) + 1 order by 1
```

I want the output in this format

```
12/31 10 PM
12/31 11 PM
01/01 12 AM
01/02 1 AM
...
```

### Update

This provides a timeline for a dynamic date range (break-down into every hour regardless there is data) report upper management wants to see. However, due to space constraint, showing 4-digit year is a waste. This is not a puzzle game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD HH AM';

SELECT to_date('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + (FLOOR(rownum/24) + (MOD(rownum-1, 24)/24)) dt
 FROM DUAL 
 CONNECT BY rownum <= ((to_date('01/02/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')+(1/23)) - to_date('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + (MOD(rownum, 24)/24)) * 24
ORDER BY 1;
```

Output:

```
DT        
-----------
12/31 12 AM
12/31 01 AM
12/31 02 AM
12/31 03 AM
12/31 04 AM
12/31 05 AM
12/31 06 AM
12/31 07 AM
12/31 08 AM
12/31 09 AM
12/31 10 AM
12/31 11 AM
12/31 12 PM
12/31 01 PM
12/31 02 PM
12/31 03 PM
12/31 04 PM
12/31 05 PM
12/31 06 PM
12/31 07 PM
12/31 08 PM
12/31 09 PM
12/31 10 PM
01/01 12 AM
01/01 01 AM
01/01 02 AM
01/01 03 AM
01/01 04 AM
01/01 05 AM
01/01 06 AM
01/01 07 AM
01/01 08 AM
01/01 09 AM
01/01 10 AM
01/01 11 AM
01/01 12 PM
01/01 01 PM
01/01 02 PM
01/01 03 PM
01/01 04 PM
01/01 05 PM
01/01 06 PM
01/01 07 PM
01/01 08 PM
01/01 09 PM
01/01 10 PM
01/01 11 PM
01/02 12 AM
01/02 01 AM
01/02 02 AM
01/02 03 AM
01/02 04 AM
01/02 05 AM
01/02 06 AM
01/02 07 AM
01/02 08 AM
01/02 09 AM
01/02 10 AM
01/02 11 AM
01/02 12 PM
01/02 01 PM
01/02 02 PM
01/02 03 PM
01/02 04 PM
01/02 05 PM
01/02 06 PM
01/02 07 PM
01/02 08 PM
01/02 09 PM
01/02 10 PM
01/02 11 PM
```

71 rows selected

If you want to specify the start hour and end hour, use query below, I just modified the CONNECT BY and ORDER BY clause of my first query.

```
SELECT to_date('12/31/2017 10:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM') + (FLOOR(rownum/24) + (MOD(rownum-1, 24)/24)) dt
   FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY rownum <= CEIL(((to_date('01/01/2018 02:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM') - to_date('12/31/2017 10:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')) * 24))+1
  ORDER BY rownum;
```

Output

```
DT        
-----------
12/31 10 PM
12/31 11 PM
01/01 12 AM
01/01 01 AM
01/01 02 AM
```

Comment: looking good. question is do I have to run this every time? `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD HH AM';`

Comment: No, it's up to you, you can use the TO_CHAR function with the format you want

Comment: if the begin and end have hour, say '12/31/2017 10 PM' to '01/01/2018 02 AM' it returns more entries.

Comment: I see, I added another query, you can use it, but I found a little problem on that new added query, when your end time is 01/02/2018 05:00 AM, the last record will be 01/02 06:00 AM, it's because of the CEIL function, I tried FLOOR function but it will have also a problem if end time is 01/02/2018 06:00 AM because the last record will be 01/02 05 AM. So my suggestion is you can add a filter (make my query a sub-query and add a condition WHERE DT <= END_TIME)

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
   SELECT to_char( trunc(sysdate) - ((ROWNUM-2)/24) - 1 , 'MM/DD HH PM') dt -- "pm" part is case-sensitive. i.e. if "PM" or "pm" are used to get upp[low]er results, respectively.   
     FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ( trunc(sysdate) - to_date('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) + 2 
    ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC;
```

or replace `trunc(sysdate)` with your date `to_date('&&myDate','MM/DD/YYYY')` :

```
    SELECT to_char( to_date('&&myDate','MM/DD/YYYY') - ((ROWNUM-2)/24) - 1 , 'MM/DD HH PM') dt
      FROM DUAL 
   CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ( to_date('&&myDate','MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date('12/31/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) + 2 
     ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC; -- for your case '&&myDate' is called with 01/02/2018

  DT
---------------------------------
  12/31 10 PM
  12/31 11 PM
  01/01 12 AM
  01/01 01 AM
```

Comment: this output does not give me the desired data: 
`12/31 10 PM
12/31 11 PM
01/01 12 AM
01/02 1 AM`
...

Comment: @Jeb50 ok, i've edited according to your desired results, but there's a little problem with the last row where i get `01/01 01 AM`, while yours has `01/02 01 AM`. What could be the logic behind yours?

Comment: Ozhan this is to feed some coordinates for a dynamic report, say activity for executives, so they can pick a date and hour window. Dose it answer the question?

Comment: @Jeb50 sure, dynamic, if you use the first one, or the second with bind variable(now,i'm updating) instead of '01/02/2018'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would be best handled outside your database honestly, but if you need to handle it there, Oracle uses `EXTRACT` to pull parts of a date:

You will want to `EXTRACT(Month FROM dt)`, `EXTRACT(Day FROM dt)` and `EXTRACT(Hour FROM dt)` then concatenate the results. The hour portion will be in 24 hour time, so you will need to handle that, perhaps by using `CASE`. Something like this, using a version of your query as a subquery(I am not an oracle expert, but I don't think your query actually returns the dateTime, it needs to for this):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(Month FROM dt)||'/'||EXTRACT(Day FROM dt)||' '||
  (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(Hour FROM dt)>12 
    THEN (EXTRACT(Hour FROM dt)- 12)|| ' PM' 
    ELSE EXTRACT(Hour FROM dt)|| ' AM')
FROM [...]
```

Comment: You may need to cast/convert the extract result before you can compare with 12, or subtract 12.