# get data in 'n' hours interval between two dates oracle

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, intervals

i am trying to get data between two dates in an 'n' hour intervals ...  the problem is that i am not getting desired result after 8 hour intervals ... my value in 'n' interval can range up to any number between 1 to 120.
Following is the Pseudo code of what i am tying to do:

**--  i first select number of hours between two dates**

```
 SELECT
24 * (SYSDATE - to_date('2018-04-16 15:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) AS diff_hours
FROM dual;
```

**-- Then i use the above value in CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ROUND((hours between two dates/n),0) to get data in n intervals**

```
  SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - (rownum/ROUND((24/n),0)),'HH24') as the_hour
        FROM dual
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ROUND((hours between two dates/n),0) ;
```

**Sample query**

```
 SELECT
    24 * (SYSDATE - to_date('2018-04-16 15:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) AS diff_hours
FROM dual;
  SELECT TRUNC(sysdate - (rownum/ROUND((24/8),0)),'HH24') as the_hour
        FROM dual
      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ROUND((724/8),0) ;
```

How can i change above query to get data in 'n' hour intervals between two dates, with n being any number of hours?

Comment: this could be a duplicate question to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716473/list-of-date-hours-between-two-dates/48719233#48719233

Comment: @eifla001 no this is not what i need

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first `ROUND()` in your `SELECT`

```
SELECT   TRUNC (SYSDATE - (ROWNUM / (24 / 9)), 'HH24') AS the_hour
   FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY   ROWNUM <= ROUND ( (724 / 9), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  SELECT TO_DATE(:p_date1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + (FLOOR((rownum*:p_interval)/24) + (MOD((rownum*:p_interval), 24)/24)) dt
    FROM DUAL 
 CONNECT BY (rownum*:p_interval) <= ((TO_DATE(:p_date2, 'MM/DD/YYYY')+.5) - TO_DATE(:p_date1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') + (MOD((rownum*:p_interval), 24)/24)) * 24
   ORDER BY 1;
```